Poisson summation formula for Dirichlet character on congruence class
Let $q,r\in \mathbb{N}$, and $\chi$ be primitive Dirichlet character mod $q$ with $(q,r)\neq 1$, $(b,r)=1$. $F$ is a smooth function.
Then what we will get after applying the Poisson summation on the flowing sum
$$ \sum_{n\equiv b(mod\,\, r)} \chi(n) F\left(\frac{n}{X}\right) = ?$$

i'll keep my answer to a comment because i'm not sure if i'm right, but basically i think all you can is write the character and progression in terms of additive characters and apply Poisson to that

Does $n$ range over the integers or just the natural numbers? In the former case you should do what tomos suggested above.

$n$ runs over natural numbers.

If i did correctly, at the end we will get the following Gauss type sum:  Let $(q, r)=c$ and $\overline{q/c}. q/c \equiv 1 (mod, r/c)$            $$\sum_{a(mod,q)}\chi(a)e\left( \frac{an}{q. r/c } - \frac{an \overline{q/c}}{ r/c } \right).$$ I want simplify the  Gauss sum.
